# Empty snippet when using "sulu_snippet_load_by_area"

Tags: php, twig, sulu

The snippet return "null" when I try to get it in my varaible.

```
 {% set snippets = sulu_snippet_load_by_area('banner') %}
 {{ dump(snippets) }}
```

and

```
<key>banner</key>

<meta>
    <title lang="en">Banner</title>
    <title lang="fr">Bannière</title>
</meta>

<areas>
    <area key="banner">
        <meta>
            <title lang="fr">Banniere</title>
            <title lang="en">Banner</title>
        </meta>
    </area>
</areas>

<properties>
    ....
```

I try to use the sulu_snippet_load_default instead but it returns me an empty array. If I try to dump the content.snippet I manage to get my values.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDOQu.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The snippet will only be returned when you are **creating first a snippet** of that type. going to your **Webspace** click on **Default Snippets** Tab and **select the snippet** you did create before.

Keep in mind the `sulu_snippet_load_by_area` will return you the single snippet you did select there. So not an array of snippets.