# sulu_snippet_load_by_area returns null

Tags: symfony, twig, sulu

I am facing the same issue described in this one [Empty snippet when using "sulu_snippet_load_by_area"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69868538/empty-snippet-when-using-sulu-snippet-load-by-area)

I have this snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<template xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template-1.0.xsd">

    <key>test</key>

    <meta>
        <title lang="en">Test</title>
        <title lang="de">Test</title>
    </meta>

    <areas>
        <area key="test-default">
            <meta>
                <title lang="en">Test</title>
                <title lang="de">Test</title>
            </meta>
        </area>
    </areas>

    <properties>
        <property name="title" type="text_line" mandatory="true">
            <meta>
                <title lang="en">Title</title>
                <title lang="de">Titel</title>
            </meta>

            <tag name="sulu.node.name"/>
        </property>

        <property name="entry" type="text_line" mandatory="true">
            <meta>
                <title lang="de">Entry</title>
                <title lang="en">Entry</title>
            </meta>
        </property>

    </properties>
</template>
```

As described in the other task I created a corresponding snippet in the Snippet Section of my webspace. I also created other snippets but none of them provides content when called with sulu_snippet_load_by_area()
So, what is going wrong?

Comment: Did you try using an underscore instead of the dash? (test-default => test_default)

Comment: It was a lack of configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the "official" way, but I added the newly created snippet as default snippet to my webspace. And then it is loaded.